# Unable to use geocoding with url launcher flutter

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, geocoding, url-launcher

I am using flutter and my project uses url launcher. Now i have used geocoding package but while getting dependencies (giolocator is the class name) this error occur

Because no versions of geocoding match >2.0.2 <3.0.0 and geocoding 2.0.2 depends on geocoding_platform_interface ^2.0.0, geocoding ^2.0.2 requires geocoding_platform_interface ^2.0.0.
And because geocoding_platform_interface >=2.0.0 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, geocoding ^2.0.2 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0.
And because url_launcher >=5.7.7 <6.0.0-nullsafety depends on url_launcher_platform_interface ^1.0.9 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, geocoding ^2.0.2 is incompatible with url_launcher >=5.7.7 <6.0.0-nullsafety.
So, because giolocator depends on both geocoding ^2.0.2 and url_launcher ^5.7.8, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because giolocator depends on both geocoding ^2.0.2 and url_launcher ^5.7.8, version solving failed.)]
Please help

Comment: Have you tried using a  url_launcher < 5.7.7 version?

Comment: yes. But by choosing any it works.